# making output of datefinder into list

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, date, datefinder

```
import datefinder
import pandas as pd
s = "entries are due by January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm. created 01/15/2005 by ACME Inc. and associates. here Dec. 24th, 1981 at 6pm."
match = datefinder.find_dates(s)
for m in match:
    print(m)

2017-01-04 20:00:00
2005-01-15 00:00:00
1981-12-24 18:00:00
```

The above works using `datefinder` to find dates in string. For example, `January 4th, 2017 at 8:00pm` is grabbed from `s` and is converted into `2017-01-04 20:00:00`. Now I simply want to get the output `print(m)` and turn it into a list `mm` which contains the same format as `print(m)`. I use

```
mm = []
for m in match:
    d = pd.Series(m)
    mm.append(m)

mm
[datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, 20, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 1, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(1981, 12, 24, 18, 0)]
```

But I want the output to be

```
mm 
    [2017-01-04 20:00:00,
    2005-01-15 00:00:00,
    1981-12-24 18:00:00]
```

How do I change my code to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `print(m)`, change it to `print(m.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`. `strftime` is designed to convert `datetime` objects into strings.